# Delete a div with a specific keyword in it

Tags: jquery, html

Given this html,

```
<div id="knownParent">
    <div>   <!-- This is the div to delete -->
        <a>a link</a>
        <span>the <b>keyword</b> is here somewhere and it is not repeated</span>
        <p>what I want is to delete the div containing this keyword</p>
    </div>
    <div id="knownNext"></div>
</div
```

I need to delete the div "`divToDelete`". I always know what is its parent div and its next sibling div and I can determine the div by some keyword in the div's content.

Using jquery, hoq would I do that?

Comment: `$('div').contains('keyword').remove();` ????

Comment: I assume that the ID is not really there? Otherwise you'd just use that.

Comment: @Val `.contains()` is not a method.

Comment: @Val `#knownParent` **also** contains 'keyword'

Comment: do you want to remove the keyword itself ? or the whole div ?

Comment: @matt you are right was thinking of `:contains()` my bad but still :)

Comment: @nick that code wasn't there when I answered

Comment: @Val why are you not posting this as an answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you know the parent & the next, you could also do this :

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return (
        ($(this).parent().attr("id") === "knownParent")
        &&
        ($(this).nextAll("div").attr("id") === "knownNext")
    );
}).remove();
```

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UNHpj/)

Comment: Sorry, but this would be a horribly inefficient way to do it. You'd hit every div on the page, traversing to and testing its parent and its next sibling. If you know the ID, you can get directly to within one element of the target. -1

Comment: -1. Agreed with @patrick, this is a miserable solution. [His answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073269/delete-a-div-with-a-specific-keyword-in-it/6073316#6073316) is the right way to do this.

Comment: It's a solution, a working one. It's not my fault if the OP chose this one instead of another better solution. -1 is not justified...

Comment: Here is a link showing the execution time of different solutions: [http://jsperf.com/jquery-div-removal-test/2](http://jsperf.com/jquery-div-removal-test/2). It may not be the most efficient way, but it's not that bad either.

Comment: Sylvain: Please don't take it too personally. @Matt and I aren't picking on you, just your answer. ;o) With regard to the performance test, jsPerf doesn't reset the DOM each time it runs the test, so [I reworked it without the `.remove()` call](http://jsperf.com/jquery-div-removal-test/3). I also added my `.prev()` answer. You can see the difference now, and this is using a DOM with only 3 `<div>` elements. Imagine if there were 200.

Comment: @patrick I'm not taking it personally it's just that there are answers here that does not respond to the question, and are not downvoted, some of them are even upvoted.

Comment: @Sylvain: Yeah, I know that can be frustrating. In fairness, I haven't down-voted `$("#divToDelete").remove();` because the `divToDelete` was part of the original question. But I don't see any upvotes on answers that don't respond to the question. The OP's intent was to remove a DOM element of which the parent and next sibling are known. That doesn't mean that the best solution ought to utilize both elements. But even if it did, I'd do it in a selector, like `$("#knownParent > div + #knownNext").prev()` which would still be fairly efficient, though unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @patrick My bad, there are no upvoted answers that did not deserve it. Let's stop talking about it... at least the OP has now plenty solutions to his problem !

Answer (score 5):

Use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
var keyword = 'keyword';
$('#knownParent').find('div:contains(' + keyword + ')').remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/h6E7W/

Comment: sorry matt. I didn't see your answer. Mine is nearly a duplicate.

Comment: No worries. If it's that big a deal, there's always the `delete` button.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the next sibling, then just use the [`prev()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method.

```
var knownSibling = $('#knownNext');

knownSibling.prev('div').remove();
```

This will be *much* faster than trying to use some text content to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#divToDelete").remove();
```

Comment: That was just an example, the OP wants to delete that div, based on criteria.

Comment: cant do, i dont know the id..in fact, that was a typo, that div doesnt even have an id (i wish it had!) thats why am using the parent, the sibling and the keyword to pin it down

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div:contains("keyword")', '#knownParent').remove();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this JQuery API : http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

here is a quick example;

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>JQuery Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="mydiv">
    bar foo poo
  </div>

  <a id="deleteDiv" href="#">delete div</a>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#deleteDiv").click(function() {
      $("#mydiv:contains('foo')").remove();
    });

  });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```